# Self-adjoint operator $L$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An operator $L$ is called self-adjoint when it stands that $$L=\widetilde{L}$$
So to check if the operator is self-adjoint do I have to check if $$(v,Lu)=(Lv,u)$$ when we have defined the dot product as followed:
$$(v,u)=\int_a^b v^* udx, \text{ where } v^* \text{ is the complex conjugate of } v$$??

Comment: It depends on the context. If $L$ is not defined on the full space, you also have to check that $L$ and $\tilde{L}$ have the same domain, otherwise you only prove that $L$ is symmetric.

Comment: So, to show that $L$ is symmetric, do I have to show that $Lu=\widetilde{L}u$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator):

> In mathematics, a *self-adjoint operator* on a complex vector space V
>   with inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an operator (a
>   linear map A from V to itself) that is its own adjoint: $\langle
>  Av,w\rangle=\langle v,Aw\rangle$. If V is finite-dimensional with a
>   given basis, this is equivalent to the condition that the matrix of A
>   is Hermitian, i.e., equal to its conjugate transpose A*.

Note that this is *not* the same as *symmetric*, which means that $A=A^T$.

So yes, you have to check that $(v,Lu)=(Lv,u)$.

Comment: Ahaa.. Ok!! Thanks a lot!!! :-)